# Firebase push() in iOS

Tags: ios, firebase

Is there any equivalent of Firebase.push() method for iOS API which is available in API for Javascript or Java ?

I couldn't find it in API reference for iOS.

What I need is to push data to the new child location based on timestamp (I prefer server not client timestamp) and return that reference in the block.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes!  We renamed it [childByAutoId](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios-api/Classes/Firebase.html#//api/name/childByAutoId) to be more consistent with iOS naming conventions, but it behaves the same as ref.push().  If you want to set data (equivalent of ref.push(data)), you can do `[[ref childByAutoId] setValue:data]`

Comment: it seems to behave differently on iOS - on web API it gives a number as the key, but a UUID on iOS http://imgur.com/a/6y7de

Comment: how can you set the value to true?  For instance: if I wrote: let requestId = historyRef.childByAutoId(), then: driverRef.child(requestId).setValue(true), I get an error: 'Bool' is not convertible to 'Any?' - How can I fix this.